# Initialize a jQuery gallery on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery script to include galleries on my page https://www.jqueryscript.net/gallery/Responsive-Gallery-Thumbnail-Nav-jQuery.html

I have a dynamic number of galleries and all are hidden but one on page load. Each gallery has an associated "view gallery" button. When the user clicks the individual gallery's view button, that gallery will show and all other galleries will be hidden.

Everything works fines except for the thumbnail navigation. The initial gallery that is shown on page load displays correctly. All other galleries function but the thumbnails in the navigation are only 25px wide. If I resize my browser (even by 1px) the thumbnail images will resize to their correct width.

Here is how I am initializing the galleries:

```
$('.service-slider').each(function(key, item) {
    var slideIdName = 'slider' + key;

    this.id = slideIdName;

    var sliderID = '#' + slideIdName;

    $(sliderID).gallery({
        singleLine: true,
        height: 650,
        items: 4,
        480: {
        items: 2,
        height: 400,
        thmbHeight: 100
        },
        768: {

        items: 4,
        height: 500,
        thmbHeight: 120
        },
        600: {

        items: 3
        },
        992 : {

        items: 5,
        height: 350
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried to set the code above as a function and run the function each time a "view gallery" button was clicked. That didn't work.

Comment: How do you hide your other galleries?

Comment: They are in a parent div that is hidden (display: none;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container-gallery').gallery({
  height: 650,
  items: 6,
  480: {
    items: 2,
    height: 400,
    thmbHeight: 100
  },
  768: {

    items: 3,
    height: 500,
    thmbHeight: 120
  },
  600: {

    items: 4
  },
  992 : {

    items: 5,
    height: 350
  }
});

$('.container-gallery').gallery({
  customControls: {
    prevButton: prevContent,
    nextButton: nextContent
  }
});
```

you must use them separately and not use them nested inside eachother

I made it work on [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/darg1coh/3/)